# Handsontable Performance Issues On Updating Comments to Cells

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a function that updates a comment to every single cell in a row. This function is called many times by a higher level function that loops through every row in the table and determines what comments to apply.

This all works fine. See a simplified version of the code below.

```
// Loop through all hot rows and determine comment to apply
var loopThroughHotRows = function (hot) {
   var rows = hot.getSourceData().length;
   for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       var comment = "some comment determined by another function";
       applyResponseCommentsToRow(hot, comment, i);
   }
}

// Apply comments to a whole row in a passed handsontable
var applyCommentsToRow = function (hot, comment, logicalrow) {
  var cols = hot.countCols();
  var commentsPlugin = hot.getPlugin('comments');
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // render being issued for each comment set.
    // need to restrict rendering somehow.
    commentsPlugin.setCommentAtCell(logicalrow, i, comment);
  }
}
```

The problem is that each time a comment is applied to a cell. The rendering of the entire handsontable instance is initiated. Causing the web browser to get blocked/chug/become very slow and responsive until all the rendering is complete.

So my question is. Is there some way to prevent Handsontable from rendering each time that a new comment is applied to a cell? Either by temporarily disabling all rendering or adding the comments in a different manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring out a solution to this on my own. If you set the comment of the cell by calling the hot.getCellMeta() function.

This actually bypasses the re-rendering of the handsontable. See updated function below.

```
// Apply comments to a whole row in a passed handsontable
var applyCommentsToRow = function (hot, comment, logicalrow) {
  var cols = hot.countCols();
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // New method of writing comment to cell. Does not cause handsontable re-render.
    hot.getCellMeta(logicalrow, i).comment = {'value':responseComments};
  }
  // Call render once after all comments have been assigned to row!
  hot.render();
}
```

Comment: Does it work for anything then ? (Changing color cell, changing values, etc...)

Comment: @Fab hmm it appears to work for any object property part of the getCellMeta() function. See example fiddle below. Just tested it with changing the class name to change the cell colour. https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/wpczdqn2/8/. There doesnt appear to be a property for value in this function. Maybe there is another method though you can use to access the under lying object which stores the value property though?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can think of to enhance the speed of your function is to ***not*** change the comment in cells when it's not necessary. (old comment value = new comment value). To do that, you simply have to compare both String before doing setCommentAtCell :

```
if(comment.localeCompare(hot.getPlugin('comments').getCommentAtCell(logicalRow,i)) != 0)
    commentsPlugin.setCommentAtCell(logicalRow, i, comment);
```

I used a little example to quickly test this change that you can find in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03yLy8wg/). (For the sake of 'quick testing', I trigger the change comment for every cell when I **copy** : whether you use ctrl+C in the table, or you use the action **copy** in the context menu).

You will see that it will freeze the first time (as every cell will be modified), but the second time there is no freeze at all since the changes are not necessary.

Comment: Now if everytime you trigger the changes, many cells are changed, this enhancement will not do a great difference for your problem. I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation a way to speed up the setCommentAtCell function. SO unless someone find anything about this, you might consider giving up on using this plugin...

Comment: I have been liasing with the handsontable team on this and was able to come up with a better solution to prevent the re-render of the hot every time a comment is assigned to a cell. The trick lies in how we add this comment information to the table. As opposed to using the .setComment at cell function. We can use the hot.updateSettings({cell:cellproperties}) method. This reduces the re-rendering of the table from cells^2 to just cell count. See example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/wpczdqn2/.

Comment: also the team has a project scheduled to allow rendering of specific cells. See their response ... "currently, we cannot pick which cells we want to rerender. When a single cell is changed the whole table gets rerendered. 

We will be adding an option that set ranges of cells. That option will allow us to distinguish cells that we want to rerender. The project is scheduled for Q3 and should start in September.

You can track the progress and leave your vote for the idea at our Trello Roadmap  https://trello.com/c/m9KTygSV/80-refactor-re-write-of-renderers"

Comment: I figured this one out myself. See answer I have posted if you are interested.